# What does "Build using the CMake-generated files." mean?

Tags: c, build, cmake, opencl, lib

I'm trying to build the OpenCL ICD library for a program that I'm developing (Gotta get that OpenCL.lib file somehow, and the .lib files that the SDKs give me are all garbage that doesn't work at all). I've made it until step 4 without problems in the build instructions:

1. Clone this repo:

   git clone https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-ICD-Loader
2. Obtain the OpenCL Headers, if you are not planning to use system OpenCL headers. Headers may be obtained from the Khronos OpenCL Headers repository.
3. Create a build directory:

   cd OpenCL-ICD-Loader
   mkdir build
   cd build
4. Invoke cmake to generate solution files, Makefiles, or files for other build systems.
   cmake ..

But then comes step 5:
Build using the CMake-generated files.

What in the world does that mean?? How do I do that?

Error from make:

```
[  4%] Building C object CMakeFiles/OpenCL.dir/loader/icd.c.o
/cygdrive/d/OpenCL/OpenCL-ICD-Loader/loader/icd.c: In function 'loader_get_next_path':
/cygdrive/d/OpenCL/OpenCL-ICD-Loader/loader/icd.c:199:25: error: 'PATH_SEPARATOR' undeclared (first use in this function)
  199 |     next = strchr(path, PATH_SEPARATOR);
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Should be just `make`.  The output of cmake is normally Makefiles where the default for make is to build your target.

Comment: @stark I cd'd to the directory where the makefile was and got this error:

Comment: Where are you cd'ing?  You should run make in the same directory where you ran cmake.

Comment: @stark How do I format the error into code? It says I can't enter  because there are too many words :/

Comment: @stark Nevermind I gave up and used pastebin instead https://pastebin.com/EGeDF2pf

Comment: I added the error.  Looks like a mismatch between the version of OpenCL and the environment where you are building.